# Delete the line beginning with given string and the following n lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've a file HTML like the one below:

```
      <tr>
        <td>SOMETHING1</td>
        <td>SOMETHING2</td>
        <td>SOMETHING3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SOMETHING1</td>
        <td>SOMETHING2</td>
        <td>SOMETHING3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SOMETHING1</td>
        <td>SOMETHING2</td>
        <td>SOMETHING3</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <br>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:;" onmousedown="toggleDiv('20161023');">Sunday 23 ...   </a></h3>
    <br>
    <div class="time_div" id="20161023" style="display:none">
    <p class="dep_parag">Test automation on Sunday 23 October</p>
    <table id="table" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">

    <tr>
        <td>SOMETHING1</td>
        <td>SOMETHING2</td>
        <td>SOMETHING3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SOMETHING1</td>
        <td>SOMETHING2</td>
        <td>SOMETHING3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SOMETHING1</td>
        <td>SOMETHING2</td>
        <td>SOMETHING3</td>
      </tr>
```

As you can see there is a list of table row divided by a section with some javascript (the section start with  and finish with )

This is just an extraction of a html page containing more than 300.000 table row!

I've to delete the section with the javascript, beacuse i need just a long table row list, clean, without nothing between them.

Instead of doing it manually, that is crazy, i would like something (Regular expression) to clean the file with just one click (I use to run simple regular expression on NOTEPAD++, but this one is a little bit hard for me)

I was thinking at something like:

**delete all the row from  to *cellspacing="0">***

Or

**delete all the row from  and following 8 lines.**

Can someone be so gentle to help me with this regex?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: not sure if understand correctly, try using search mode regex,  replace this regex with empty       </table>\r\n(.*\r\n){2}.*javascript.*\r\n(.*\r\n){4}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are not fussed about irregular whitespace, how about a search pattern of:

```
</table>.*?<table.*?>
```

With an empty "*Replace with*" string, tick the "*Regular expression*" and "*. matches newline*" options.

Comment: You have to make the `.*` not greedy (ie. `.*?`) or you will delete much more than is wanted.

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct - lost in translation from my N++ window! Updated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand which part do you want to remove (my understanding is from `</table>` to `cellspacing="0">` ? ), but it should be fairly easy. Do you mean something like this ?

```
<a href="javascript([^\n]+\r\n){5}
```

Comment: I know. But removing 8 lines below the </table> is just as simple.

Comment: Taking advantage of the table structure, just <\/table>.*<tr> => <tr> will do the trick. (have to tick the . Include new line option) Some NPP version on my PC used to have a bug : replacing with empty string in regex will make the NPP crash. So usually I replace with sth. But I agree non greedy match is the formal way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression will work with flag **s** single-line for php,python, for java initiate expression with **DOTALL** option

```
\<\/table\>.+?(?=javascript\:\;).+?(?=\<table.+?cellspacing\=\"0\"\>)\<table.+?cellspacing\=\"0\"\>
```

Comment: Why are you escaping all these characters?

Comment: It is always safe enough to precede a non-alpha numeric character with a \ to indicate that the character stands for itself.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions